# Trying to Remove Leading and Trailing Spaces using Trim but its not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I've tried

```
update Table_Name set Name=Trim(Name)
```

But its not working ..the string in which i want to remove leading and trailing spaces is as follows:

```
'  % of critical assets, that should be monitored via PdM technologies, are being monitored '
```

which is currently in the column named as Name from my table

Comment: ["Works fine on my machine."](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e82a88e929f4eb296edbbf4ad5b961c9) Take the time to provide us with a full [mre].

Comment: May be it isn't spaces... tabs or something else that looks like a space.

Comment: Try looking at a different representation of the string, e.g. `Convert(VarBinary, Name)` will give you a hexadecimal view. A normal ASCII space should show up as `0x20`.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error message, or are no characters removed?

Comment: have you checked to make sure these are "whitespace" characters?  maybe they are control characters that can't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype is CHAR or NCHAR, you cannot remove trailing spaces. You can only do that on VARCHAR/NVARCHAR

Comment: But it would remove leading spaces - as OP desires and as represented in the single sample.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
update Table_Name set Name=LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))
```

instead of TRIM

Comment: _By default, the TRIM function removes the space character from both the beginning and the ending ends of the string. This behavior is equivalent to LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))._ So your answer is same as what OP is using.

Comment: But its applicable only from 2017 version, may be he is using a older version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Then he would be complaining about _'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name._ Until OP clarifies what "its not working" means, this answer is not useful.

Comment: Why would this work when TRIM didn't work?